# powershell computer inventory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i have to identify all the laptops in our organization. 
single OU named "computers". all the computers are named by the name of the user using it. no information about the computer type. 
in order to deploy a soft on laptops only, i have to "isolate" them. 
i ran the following script.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlyContinue"
 $coms=Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com" |select -exp name
Foreach($com in $coms)
{
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -comp $com  | Select-Object PCSystemType,Name,Manufacturer,Model | format-table
}
```

it works pretty good. but not so easy to sort.

i wanted to make it better, and ran the following:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlyContinue"
 $coms=Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com" |select -exp name
Foreach($com in $coms)
{
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -comp $com| Select-Object PCSystemType,Name,Manufacturer,Model | format-table
if ($com.PCSystemType -eq '2'){Write-host "$com is a laptop"} 
else {Write-host "$com is a desktop"} 
}
```

i now have this result:

```
COMP1 is a desktop
COMP2 is a desktop
COMP3 is a desktop
COMP4 is a desktop
LAPTOP1 is a desktop
LAPTOP2 is a desktop
LAPTOP3 is a desktop
```

Both laptops and desktops are desktops according my script. 
what i did wrong? 
any tip would help! thanks

Comment: Never use formatters (e.g. `Format-Table`) where you aren't **only** outputting to the console.  You have unusable objects.  Additionally, `PCSystemType` is a `uint16` type, so compare it to a number: `$com.PCSystemType -eq 2`

Comment: The property `PCSystemType` is not a string, but a `uint16`, per piping the result of `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property *` to `Get-Member`. Try `if ($com.PCSystemType -eq 2) ...`. Also, @TheIncorrigible1 is correct; you should not be using `Format-Table` here.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `Format-*` cmdlets is to create *pretty* output to the console; to be human-readable.  It does this by creating different objects from what you pass in to accomplish an ends.  As a result, you have unusable objects and are essentially accessing `$null`.

Removing `| Format-Table` will fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for your answers. i made the corrections you suggested.    if ($com.PCSystemType -eq 2)
and removed     | format-table. but the result is quite the same. laptops are still marked as desktops

Comment: @Fab Have you looked at the laptop's wmi information to confirm your assumptions (`PCSystemType` being `2`)?

Comment: yup, i did on my own laptop. (which is correctly named. but is for testing)

    PCSystemType Name          Manufacturer          Model
------------ ----          ------------          -----
           2 LAPTOP-FABIEN ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. UX490UAR

Comment: I'd suggest breaking into the debugger to see where the logic is breaking down then @Fab

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of your WMI query in a variable before evaluating it in your `if` loop.

Slightly modified version:

```
$coms = @("localhost")

Foreach($com in $coms) {
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -comp $com

    switch ($wmi.PCSystemType) {
        '0' { "$com is a Unspecified " }
        '1' { "$com is a Desktop " }
        '2' { "$com is a Mobile " }
        '3' { "$com is a Workstation " }
        '4' { "$com is a Enterprise Server" }
        '5' { "$com is a SOHO Server" }
        '6' { "$com is a Appliance PC" }
        '7' { "$com is a Performance Server" }
        '8' { "$com is a Maximum" }
        Default { "Unable to get correct value for $com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Adamar. it work better. i now have something like this:
pc1 is a Desktop
pc2 is a Mobile
pc3 is a Mobile
pc4 is a Desktop
Unable to get correct value for pc5
but, pc5 is a laptop, online. i just ran the command on this laptop and get a pcsystemtype 2. 
i dont understand why

Comment: What result do you get when you run the Get-WmiObject command on pc5? Does it return the correct PCSystemType?